# MongoDB `cursor.count` returning 0 despite non-empty collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve the number of documents in my database that match a certain hash value, but the `count()` function seems to return 0 no matter how many documents are in the collection. This is the code I have:

```
var cursor = collection.find({hash_val: current_hash_val}, {response: 1,_id: 0});


cursor.count(function(count) {
    if(count == 1) {
        console.log("Found a unique document. Count is %d",count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });
    }
    else if(count > 1){
        console.log("Found multiple documents. Count is %d", count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });

    }
    else{
        console.log("Did not find any documents. Count is %d", count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });

    }
});
```

I have several documents in the collection that match `current_hash_val`, but my code always jumps to the `else` statement. However, the `forEach` function shows me several records printed to the console. Can someone explain whether I'm using the count function wrong or whether this is incorrect behavior on MongoDB's part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's because the callback function takes two arguments, the error and the count value, so it's assigning the error value that is probably `null` to `count`, so try getting the error before the count value on the callback function:

```
var cursor = collection.find({hash_val: current_hash_val}, {response: 1,_id: 0});


cursor.count(function(err, count) {
    if(count == 1) {
        console.log("Found a unique document. Count is %d",count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });
    }
    else if(count > 1){
        console.log("Found multiple documents. Count is %d", count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });

    }
    else{
        console.log("Did not find any documents. Count is %d", count);
        cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });

    }
});
```

You can check the [count example](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#count) for more info

Comment: That seems to have done it. Is it a convention to always accept `err` as the first parameter in such callbacks?

Comment: Yes, check this link for more information: http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/ (I've learned from it)

Comment: You're welcome! I've suffered a lot when started with node because of this D: can you please accept the answer just so we close this matter?

Comment: It said I had to wait a little while before accepting. Just did it.